# не загружается war на Glassfish

Tags: java, веб-программирование, glassfish, war

Добавил war в application нажал launch. В итоге не работает(. В чем проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что должно было получиться?  Что выводится в логах?

Comment: @defaultlocale все заработало через Tomcat)